# How to replace plus sign to space from url using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

This is my testing url

```
index.html?n=abc+def
```

So, now fetching abc+def from url but i want to fetch `'abc def'`(with space not plus sign).

Anyone give me proper solution.

Comment: "abc+def".replace("+", "");

Comment: See [ask] in the Help Center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use simple javascript `replace()` function as below

```js
var str = "abc+def";
str = str.replace("+"," ");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 'abc+def'
a = a.replace('+', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 'abc+def';    //Fetch The URL get value
var out = value.replace(/\+/g,' ');
console.log(out);
```

Comment: Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. You should update your answer to explain what this does and how it solves the problem.